# How to send a variable inside of a function to be accessed in another file in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have 2 files named test.js and test2.js , I write a function in test1.js which stores a value in a variable from the function call, but I am unable to access that value in the variable in test2.js file.

Comment: Please show your code. Without knowing what exactly you are doing we don't know what you are doing wrong (or whether what you want is possible at all). However, this sounds like a timing issue you to me. How do you ensure that you only access the variable in `test2.js` *after* the function from `test1.js` was called?

Comment: hey @FelixKling, I have added the example, let me know if you need anything

Comment: If the initialization logic really needs to be async, let the first file export a promise with the results (or export a function that returns that promise) and use the value of the promise in your second file. You are not showing how `init` relates to `getAll` but right now the problem is that you can't know when the values of `det` and `fine` are available.

Comment: @FelixKling, how would I need to approach if the init method does not need to be async ?

Comment: Basically the same except that your exported function can return the values directly. That's basically what this answer showed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73829768/218196. There will still be the problem that you need to ensure that `init` is called before`getAll`.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the variable in a global scope first in the initial script and assign it (without redeclaring) you can achieve this pretty simply. Perhaps show your code so can see a bit better what your issue is?

```
//test1.js
let test = 'test';
function changeTest(change = null) {
    test = change || test;
}

//test2.js
(() => {
    console.log(`GLOBAL VARIABLE: ${test}`); // test is 'test'
    changeTest('changed');
    console.log(`AFTER CHANGE: ${test}`); // test is 'changed'
})();
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for more information on JS scope management

Answer (score 0):

So it is technically feasible but maybe not recommended.

```
# file 1
let test1 = 0;
function init1 {test1 = 2;};
init1();
export function getTest1() {return test1};
```

```
# file 2
import { getTest1 } from './file1';
function logTest1() {
  console.log(getTest1());
}
```